# how to create saveChanges callback function in grid kendo mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm having some timing issues and was wondering if there is a way for `saveChanges` to have a callback when it's save is complete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you add code below:

```
.Events(e => e.RequestEnd("RequestEnd"))
```

and create javascript function

```
function RequestEnd(e) {
    if (e.type == "update") {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Do you now how can I get if savechanges has been success or not?